# callback from customAdapter to main activity passing through a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i'm new here and in android development.
I try to describe my case...sorry if i'm not very clear.

The mainActivity holds a fragmente holding a listView generated by a customAdapter.
The customAdapter generates its own events and defines an interface to manage them.
I need to implements the callback method in the mainActivity and have two options:
1) implement the customAdapter interface in the fragment to generate a new set of events and define a new fargmentInterface to pass them to the mainActivity
2) implement the customAdapter interface in the main activity and set the customAdapter listener to the mainActivity from the fragment

Maybe it's the same, maybe it's philosophy, or maybe there's a right and a wrong way.
Thanks

Comment: what you want to achieve exactly? i just understand from question is you want some call back but can you explain it with your real case?

Comment: do you want to have a communication link between Fragment and Activity ?

Comment: sorry for my english.  I populate the listView with a cursor from a db.  when the user update a value in the listView the main activity has to update the db. In the middle there is a fragment.  So...is it right the fragment sets the customAdapter listenerto the mainActivity?  or is it better the fragment implements the customAdapter interface?